# Control overhead of ExecutorService in Android (JAVA)

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a long heaving task want to be done in background, gradually, without affecting UI performance.

Curerntly I am using ExecutorService ( Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor ), but it slows down UI.

The task involved Full Text Searching indexing using SQLITE FTS, which is really heavy.

Can I specify for example %10 CPU time to a service?

Comment: Did you tried using newSingleThreadExecutor() with a ThreadFactory which creates a Thread and sets its priority to minimum to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @Luksprog No didn't, will test it now,thanks.